# Spltting a string returns undefined error

Tags: angular

I have returned data of any from an API call.  I believe the data is a string delimited by semicolons.  I am trying to split the string so I can display the sub strings in the html via string interpolation and then make use of each sub string in sebsequent page. I tried splitting the data in the component code and keep getting back 'split not recognized on undefined'.

I have searched for alternatives like Slice but can't find much of anything.

TS Code:

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  items: any;
  itemsArray: string[];

  constructor(private ailmentService: AilmentService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ailmentService.selectAilment(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.problemId).subscribe(data => this.items = data);
    this.itemsArray = (this.items as string).split(';');
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
<td>{{item}}</td>
```

Results are

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: `this.itemsArray = (this.items as string).split(';');` This line should be inside `subscribe(//here)`

Comment: What is `console.log(this.items)` inside `subscribe()`?

Comment: Check your API response. I suspect, you are storing a JSON object to this.items.

Comment: what is this.items?

Comment: I am having trouble with the syntax of placing (this.items as string).split(';'); in subscribe.  Could you please show the proper syntax for that?

Comment: this.items.toString()

Comment: but tell me the what is the original data type of `this.items`

Comment: @oakrun show the `console.log(this.items)`?

Comment: Hi here is the result of console.log(this.items) - ["Liver/Organ Meats; Soybeans & Soy milk; Pork; Sunflower Seeds; Beans/Legumes; "]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  items: any;
  itemsArray: string[];

  constructor(private ailmentService: AilmentService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ailmentService.selectAilment(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.problemId).subscribe(data => {
            this.items = data[0];
            this.itemsArray = (this.items as string).split(';');
        });
  }
}
```

The problem with your implementation was that you were trying to split the string outside the subscribe method. These are asynchronous calls and your implementation called `split` before the server returned the data. Also the return type of yor data `this.items` was `array` so you need to iterate over this array and get the result. Assuming that you have one long string in your array, the above code should help!!